# How to skip a job in Jenkins if another job is in the failed state

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins jobs for the same project:

1. a job for the **continuous build** which will run whenever there are new commits
2. a job for the **nightly build**, triggered by time, which does the same thing but also some additional steps which take a very long time (e.g. slow tests, Sandcastle documentation generation, etcetera)

When the continuous build is failed at the end of the day, then I don't want the nightly build to run; I already know that it will fail. How do I configure this in Jenkins?

I have already considered using [conditional build steps](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin): this way I could skip build *steps*, but the build would still run. I don't want a new passed or failed build to appear in the history; I just want to skip the nightly build altogether.

Comment: Can a **nightly build** do not do the same thing and just copy last successful artifacts from **continuous build** and then do the additional steps ?

Comment: @VitaliiElenhaupt: that's certainly a good option, but I was hoping to minimize changes to my current setup. I currently have one build script with options to suppress certain steps; I'd prefer to avoid splitting it into two separate build scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried build result trigger plugin -  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin we use it for similar purpose

Comment: I had already briefly looked at the description of this plugin, but I misunderstood that the check on the monitored job was triggered whenever a build of that job completed. Apparently the monitoring is actually triggered by a schedule instead, which is exactly what I needed.